# Solve $\sin^{4}(\alpha)+4\cos^{4}(\beta)=4\sqrt{2}\sin\alpha \cos\beta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let $\alpha,\beta\in(0,\pi)$. And
$$\sin^{4}\alpha +4\cos^{4} \beta =4\sqrt{2}\sin\alpha \cos\beta$$
Then find the value of $\cos(\alpha+\beta)$?

My attempts were from similar problems I found online but all of them were futile.

**MY APPROACH:-**

The equation can be rewritten as,
$$\frac{\sin^{4}\alpha +2\cos^{4}\beta +\cos^{4}\beta +\cos^{4} \beta}{4}=\sqrt{2}\sin\alpha \cos\beta$$
I was thinking to use AM-GM inequality from here but it yield nothing,

Any hint or help is appreciated.

Comment: Try using [Sophie-Germain](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sophie-germain-identity/).

Comment: @Toby Mak, would you please elaborate the solution?

Comment: I don't have an exact idea but I have a feeling it may lead somewhere.

Comment: I found one [other question](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1769216p11601703) using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz) which should be the correct version of your question. Plotting it on Desmos gives a varying value of $\cos(\alpha + \beta)$ so I don't think this was intended by the question.